# Convert decimal reference string to decimal to show emoji with html

Tags: html, typescript, decimal, emoji

The project is built with Angular and in TypeScript. The piece of HTML is like this,

```
<span>&#9748;</span>
```

in the span there is a decimal reference and when rendering it displays as an emoji like this:
☔

Now I want to replace the decimal code `&#9748;` with a function that returns a decimal, so that the span can display different emoji based on input. Return type is string, and I want to convert it to a unicode thing. The function as this:

```
function getEmojiCode(desc: string): any {
    desc = desc.toLowerCase();
    switch (desc) {
        case 'rain': { return '&#9748;'; }
        case 'clear': { return '&#9731;'; }
        case 'clouds': { return '&#9729;'; }
        default: { return '&#9731;'; }
    }
}
```

Then I put the function in HTML

```
<span>{{getEmojiCode(res.desc)}}</span>
```

In the rendered HTML, in the place of the span, it shows the string `&#9731;` as a text, not the emoji. 
How can I convert the string to decimal code and let it show emoji in the span?

Comment: can you create a working code snippet of your code to debug it?

Comment: Are you using a templating language that's escaping the characters?

Comment: @Jack I'm using HTML. The project is with Angular. When directly type in the Unicode, it doesn't escape, when the string is returned from a function, it escapes. Then as @Amit suggests, I use `[innerHTML]="function"` in the span tag, then it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the value returned from function is added as string. I don't know what framework you are using but in angular, you would do something like this.

```
<span [innerHTML]="getEmojiCode(res.desc)"≥ </span>
```

If you are using some other framework, add the string returned from function as innerHTML to span...

Comment: I think I can't write code as my answer while being on mobile... https://www.dev6.com/Angular-2-HTML-binding this article will help you if you are using angular.

Comment: Yes, in angular. I just updated the description. But it doesn't work with the function I wrote.

Comment: Yes [innerHTML] is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

you could also do:

```
<span>{{String.fromCodePoint(Number(getEmojiCode(res.desc).slice(2,-1)))}}</span>
```

code snippet:

```js
console.log(String.fromCodePoint('&#9748;'.slice(2,-1)))
```